# Some keys are getting hard to depress on Logitech keyboard

Tags: logitech-keyboard

I bought a Logitech keyboard in April/May 2012 and it has been working fine.  For the last few days, I feel that sometimes it's getting hard to press the backspace key.

I am really unsure what happened.

When this happens, I press the key many times, and it will work for me.  I've tried to find out on Yahoo Answer, which suggested that maybe it's about dust, but I don't know to fix it for good.

What do other people do in this case?  I am reluctant to take it to a service center, because I'd rather not be without the computer for that long.

Does anyone know any good tricks to fix it?

---

http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Keyboards-and-Keyboard-Mice/Someone-help-me-what-happen-to-my-keyboard/m-p/853680

Comment: Try turning the keyboard upside down and tapping lightly on the bottom .

Comment: Return and get a replacement for your keyboard since it is only a few months old.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet would probably be to call Logitech support for a quick answer - other folks may have had the same issue so they may be able to provide a fix or let you know that you need a new keyboard. Either way, I'd give them a call first - 1-646-454-3200.

-Alex

Comment: yes, you are totally right. I have post a new link on my question about their answer on my post. I will call them in morning. Now is night for me. 4:49 AM. thanks for help :)